# Grub missing after BootMGR repair

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I had an issue in grub where it said BOOTMGR missing when I selected my windows 7 option. So I slapped in my Windows 7 disk, launched startup repair and now windows worked, however, it boots up directly into windows and GRUB does not come up.

Comment: How do you have your partitions set up? Is the Ubuntu partition on the same physical drive as Windows or separate?

Answer (score 2):

Windows did override grub. And because Win 7 does not care about other systems, nothing else showing up.

Try to repair or reinstall grub and you will be able to boot from Windows also from Ubuntu.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for only replying now, I had a busy weekend to say the least.

So this is the 'correct' answer I guess, thanks for everyone who helped.

Anyhow, I downloaded the live disk which is 64bit because my system is also 64bit. The boot-repair tool went into a hang after a few minutes and I tried it a few times. Even took my windows partition out and tried it again, still hanged and nothing happened. So I still used the live cd and did a chroot into my ubuntu partition. I the completely removed grub and the reinstalled and reconfigured it. This did not work, after one restart, so being insane an all, I did the exact same thing again and after a reboot it worked. I guess the reason boot repair didnt work is because I don't have a vanilla setup, i.o.w. one hdd with ubuntu and windows on. I have 8 hdd's where ubuntu is on partition 2 of the one and windows is on a completely different one. Anycase, just glad it works now and I didnt have to reinstall my ubuntu.